# Seeking help in understanding a point in the proof of the Hahn-Banach extension theorem

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hahn-banach-theorem

As we know, a standard proof starts in the following way: Suppose $M$ is a subspace of a vector space $X$. $x_0 \in X$ and $x_0 \notin M$. $f$ is a linear functional defined on $M$, satisfying

$$f(x) \leq p(x), \text{ }\text{ }\forall x \in M \text{ }\text{ } (1)$$

where $p$ is a sublinear functinonal.

The primary step, before the induction, is to show that there exists a functional (extended from $f$), defined on a strictly larger subspace, $M_1$, defined by $$M_1\doteq span\{m+\alpha x_0\}, \text{ } m\in M, \alpha \in R \text{ }\text{ } (2)$$

such that the functional is still bounded by $p$ on $M_1$.

I have no problem in understanding the above. But I have a question in a point in what follows. In some books, what follows is some argument like this:

If $f$ can be extended to $M_1$, then it must be true that

$$f(m+\alpha x_0)=f(m)+\alpha f(x_0) \text{ }\text{ }(3)$$

Then what we need is to show that there exists such a real constant $f(x_0)$ that would enable

$$f(m+\alpha x_0) \leq p(m+\alpha x_0) \text{ }\text{ } (4)$$

to be satisfied. Then what is remained, as we know, will be taking advantage of the RHS of equation (3) above to characterize the desired $f(x_0)$.

**My issue is**: In my opinion, in (3), $f$ is *no longer* the original $f$, for otherwise $f(m+\alpha x_0)$ would be illegal because $m+\alpha x_0 \notin M$ for $\alpha \ne 0$. Thus, how can we guarantee that the $f(m)$ on the RHS still satisfies (1), which will serve as the basis for us to characterize the proper $f(x_0)$?

**In other words, it seems to me that the above approach is deducing the extended functional from the original functional, which I feel is unwarrented.**

**I am more comfortable with an alternative approach** employed by some other authors, like the following: Let

$$g(x)\doteq f(m) + \alpha c, \text{ }\text{ } x \in M_1, m \in M, \alpha \in R \text{ }\text{ } (5)$$

**Note that the key difference from the first approach is that here we *prescribe* the form of the extended functional rather than deduce it from the original one.**

Then, we will need to show that there exists a constant $c$ that will enable this prescribed form of the extended functional to do the job, i.e. to satisfy:

$$ f(m) + \alpha c \leq p(m+\alpha x_0), \text{ } \forall m \in M, \text{ } \forall \alpha \in R \text{ }\text{ } (6)$$

Surely to prove the existence of (or equivalently to characterize) such a proper $c$ will have to play with the property (1) and is a major part of the proof.

**BTW, I think the extension theorem also provides a specific means to extend a linear functional $f$ on a subspace to a larger subspace**:

Given a linear functional, $f$, defined on a subspace $M$ that satisfies (1), we can always extend it to a linear functional, $g$, defined on a strictly larger subspace $M_1$, in the form of (7) and by properly selecting a real constant $c$, such that $g(x)$ is bounded by $p(x)$ as well.

$$g(x) \doteq f(x-\alpha(x;x_0) x_0) + \alpha(x;x_0) c, \text{ } x\in M_1 \text{ }\text{ } (7)$$

Note that, in the above, $\alpha$ is a functional from $M_1$ to $R$, parameterized by the given vector $x_0$.

Please comment and point out any mistake to help me understand. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 3) the symbol $f$ on LHS is the extended function that is being defined using the given function $f$ on $M$ and $f$ on RHS is the original function on $M$. So $f(x) \leq p(x)$ is satisfied.

In your second approach you are just saying that by properly selecting the constant  $c$ we can  make sure that $g(x) \leq p(x)$ on $M$. But how? That is where a major part of the proof lies.

Comment: Thank you so much @Kavi Rama Mruthy for your help. I think I may see your point. Given your explanation for the first approach, I think it is okay to me now. For the second approach, yes, certainly, to find a proper constant $c$, we still will need to play with $f$ on $M$ such that the range of $c$ can be characterized, and that's a major part of the proof. Actually, now I think the two approaches are actually the same. But still I prefer the second way because the notation is clearer! Is this understanding of mine better, sir?

Comment: Plus, I still think, in the first approach, some authors establish the equation (2) not in a manner of "defining", or "setting" (that's why they did not use  $:=$ or $\doteq$, but rather, by linearity of the new $f$. Having said this, I still think it is a bit wierd, because they are kind of assuming that $f$'s property can be reserved, but this is what we are trying to work out...

Comment: As I see it the two approaches are one and the same. It basically a questions of what notations you are comfortable with. For me the notations in the first approach don't cause any confusion.

Comment: Okay.. Thanks, sir. I'll prefer the 2nd way...

Comment: I actually have another place in the first approach that I am not comfortable with: Although the constant that we are trying to find depends on $x_0$, however I do not understand why this constant is equivalent to $f(x_0)$? Therefore, it appears to me that the correct way should be the second approach, i.e. to prescribe the form of the extension as  $f(m) + \alpha c$, and then to show that this form with a properly selected constant $c$, can do the job. I am an amature, and please point out where I got wrong in understanding and it will be sincerely appreciated!

Comment: $f(x_0)$ is not given to us since $x_0 \notin M$. So in the definition of $f$ on $M_1$ you have to think of $f(x_0)$ as just some constant. But once you extend $f$, say to $F$, the constant automatically becomes $F(x_0)$. I think all these confusions are only because they did not use a different symbol for the extension of $f$ from $M$ to $M_1$. So you are right in criticizing the notations in first approach.

Comment: Thanks a lot, sir. Have gotten clearer after reading your latest comment. Actually, I was not comfortable because the author (okay, not "some", but only one book in my hand that has used the 1st approach...) said "If $f$ can be extended to $M_1$, then we must have $f(m+ \alpha x_0) = f(m) + \alpha f(x_0)$ ..." This saying makes me suspect that he is not actually prescribing (i.e. defining) the form of the extension, but deducing it from linearity. May I ask, ignoring the notation issue, whether I can say that, we should prescribe the form of the extended functional rather than deduce it?